# How to associate file extensions with MIME type with Cheyenne?

Tags: webserver, mime-types, rebol, cheyenne

I'm trying to use [Cheyenne](http://cheyenne-server.org/) to serve a news feed and would like to ensure that files with the `.feed` extension are served as `application/atom+xml`. How do I configure Cheyenne to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it! In httpd.cfg in either the **globals**, **default** or **host** section ([see docs](http://cheyenne-server.org/wiki/Config/Struct)), add this directive:

```
set-mime application/atom+xml .feed
```

*or*

```
set-mime application/atom+xml [.feed .atom]
```

Comment: I didn't know that there is set-mime directive in httpd.cfg file. Accept your own answer, and thanks for sharing it :)

Answer (score 1):

Could you change extension to .rsp instead and then generate the appropriate headers that way with the feed data as a data block inside the rsp script?

Comment: Surely must be a way to do this in `httpd.cfg`?